# Setting layout constraints on a set of views programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have three `UIImageView`s (placed horizontally next to each other) that I would like to centre both horizontally and vertically inside `self.view`, with fixed horizontal spacing between them. I don't have a good grasp of using layout constraints, and know that placing them into an intermediary container and then setting `autoresizingMask` appropriately will do the trick:

```
containerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

What would it take to achieve the same effect without the use of an intermediary container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have image views `leftImageView`, `rightImageView` and `centerImageView` in your view, these constrains should do the trick:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerImageView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     multiplier:1
                                                       constant:0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerImageView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                     multiplier:1
                                                       constant:0]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[leftImage]-[centerImage]-[rightImage]"
                                                                  options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:@{@"leftImage" : leftImageView,
                                                                            @"rightImage" : rightImageView,
                                                                            @"centerImage" : centerImageView}]];
```

Make sure `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is false on each image view.